# How to send UITextField value to javascript function

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to send `UITextField` value entered in iOS app `UIWebView` to my javascript function as parameter.

I worked to invoke a JS function as below and I am done with this

```
[myWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:
 @"myFunction()"];
```

Now I want to send a value to that JS with other function, which has a parameter.

That function is as follows in JS file,

```
NoTwo(str) {
  alert ("value is "+str);
  //have some operation with str
}
```

I am reading that `UITextField` value as `NSString`.

```
NSString *nstr = [NSString stringWithFormat: uuu.text];
```

How do I call this function as did for calling `myFunction`.

In Java, it is simple string concatenation as follows.

```
[myWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:
     "NoTwo("+nstr+")"];
```

I used the following code, but there is no alert.

```
NSString *dess = name.text;
NSString *sa =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"NoTwo(%@%@", dess,@")"];

[myView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:
 sa];
```

Can anyone assist here to do this in Objective-C?

Comment: did you try the same thing in obj-c (with appropriate concatenation syntax) ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
NSString *nameStr = name.text;

NSString *javascriptString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"NoTwo('%@')", nameStr];

[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:javascriptString];
```